# Cannot insert into mysql table - mysqli error not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to insert some data into a mysql table but the process doesnt go through and I get nothing printed for the error. I don't think I'm outputting the errors correctly. Looking at php.net it seems like I'm doing the error handling properly but maybe I'm missing something.

Here is the code

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
$sqlInsert = $db->query("INSERT INTO transactions(`user_id`, `courses`, `invoice`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `mc_gross`, `email`) VALUES ('".$user_id."','".$trim."','".$invoice."','".$start_date."','".$end_date."', '".$email."')");


if($sqlInsert)
    {
    echo "Inserted successfully";
    }
    else
      {
       printf("Error: ", $db->error);

       }
```

The values for the variables are as follows

```
$custom = $_SESSION['custom'];
$user_id = $_POST['userID'];
$pwd = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$start_date = date('Y-m-d');
$end_date = date (('Y-m-d'), strtotime('+120 days'));
$invoice = date('Ymd'). mt_rand(1252,10000);
$invoice_check = $db->query("SELECT `invoice` FROM `transactions` WHERE `invoice` = $invoice");
while ($rows = $invoice_check->fetch_assoc())
{
    $invoice = date('Ymd'). mt_rand(1252,10000);   
}
$mc_gross = $_SESSION['subtotal'];
$trim = rtrim($custom, ",");
```

the var_dump for $trim is `string(17) "bio_01,calculus_01"` and the other variables just echo out normally as you'd expect.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Updated the code with $db instead of $sqlInsert. Still no output for an error.

Comment: You have 7 INSERTs and 6 VALUES. Seems like you're missing the 7th VALUE for `courses`

Comment: Since `$sqlInsert` is `false`, you obviously can't use `$sqlInsert->error`, because `false` is not an object. You have to use `$db->error`.

Comment: I've tried $db->error as well, it's just blank without any output

Comment: @Fred-ii- would the error handling tell me that I'm missing a value? Also, I put the value in.. still not getting anything

Comment: @Fahad Yes, it would say `Column count doesn't match value count`.

Comment: @Fahad I think Barmar answered that question.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I thought it would but unfortunately so far it's just blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
printf("Error: ", $sqlInsert->error);
```

to:

```
printf("Error: %s", $db->error);
```

You can't read the `error` property of `false`, because it's not an object. And you're missing the `%s` in the `printf` format string to substitute the argument.

Comment: thank you! the %s was the problem. I didn't really notice it I guess because I didnt know what it was for

Comment: Why don't you just use `echo`?

Comment: I tried originally with echo but for some reason I wasn't getting an output either. I don't really know why. I saw php.net had printf so i tried using that instead